# Changing verb in a sentence with superlative with a noun

Tags: verbs, nouns, superlatives

I wonder if I can change

> That's the furthest/farthest I've ever **run**.

with

> That's the furthest/farthest **run** I've ever did.

Comment: No, that would not be acceptable forma or colloquial English. Perhaps, using *run* as a noun, you might say, "That's the longest run I've done."

Comment: The sequence ***I have did*** is *never* valid in English, regardless of any contractions *(**have = 've**)*  and/or intensifiers *(**ever**)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say

> That's the furthest/farthest run I have ever done.